Movie about a reform school where the staff are ageless and made of stone
I remember seeing an older woman who was part of the staff at the reform school. She was showing someone that she was ageless and maybe made of some kind of stone.
I saw it around 1971. 
I also remember she picked up a pair of scissors and tried to stab her palm and it did nothing - it might have even bent the scissors.

Sounds like The Man Who Turned to Stone from 1957:

A group of 18th-century scientists, led by Dr. Murdock, have remained young after all these centuries by using electricity to suck the life out of young women. If one of the scientists misses a treatment, his skin hardens to the toughness of stone. A female prisoner [in the La Salle Detention Home for Girls] discovers why so many of her fellow inmates are disappearing, and attempts to stop them with the aid of a prison psychiatrist. 

At some point, to convince someone that it's true, a person pounds a pair of scissors into his stony hand. Here's the trailer:




Bingo! Thanks! I can even remember the young girl hanging herself but wasn't sure it was the same movie. She thought she was getting out soon and was dancing around having fun when the old matron walked in. Apparently she gave her more time on her sentence and she hung herself as a result. That's my fuzzy memory anyway.
